# Subscribing to "childrenAdded" event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there currently a way to subscribe to an event of a wrapped set, that will trigger when any element is appended to it as a child element?

Comment: Dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom ?

Comment: @AndreasAL: Close, except that question doesn't mention jQuery, which could change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing standard (DOM or jQuery) that's broadly supported. There were [mutatation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) specified in the DOM2 Events spec, but they were onerous to implement, never widely implemented, and [deprecated in the DOM3 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents).

You might be able to hack the internal `domManip` function within jQuery, which is used for most of these sorts of operations; but of course that means every release of jQuery, you have to re-hack and the internals could change such that your hack doesn't work anymore (and would only work if the caller used jQuery do to the append; even in code written for jQuery I've been known to go direct to the DOM when it was convenient). There's a script in the [answer accepted on the question AndreasAL found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219767/157247), but with the mutation events having been deprecated, well, your mileage may vary as browsers continue to update...